# html height 100% gives me more than the 100%

Tags: css

I have `html { height: 100%; }` and my div with `100% height` but it gives me extra height, yes I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009102/css-100-height-is-more-than-100), but `box-sizing: border-box` doesn't work for me. I also have a header with a height of 30px.

Comment: can you show us a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset your margins and padding?

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
```